# Determining 3D "contour-esque" shapes out of 3 dimension matrix of samples

Tags: algorithm, graphics, contour

I am trying to calculate 3D shapes out of a 3 dimensional matrix of samples. My idea is that I would have a 3 dimensional matrix of data points, with each corresponding location in (X, Y, Z) space, and from this I would determine a set of 3 dimensional shapes in the (X, Y, Z) space that each outline data points of similar values. Something similar to finding isolines, except in three dimensions.

Can anyone help me? Algorithm references or reusable code (in any language) welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: contours are 2D shapes that are section of 3D surface; if your thing was to be like them it would have(!) to be a function of four dimensions (they might be, 4th dimension can be any independent variable in your data, but you claim that you have 3D 'matrix of samples').

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the [Marching Cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes).  Also, see this [link](http://www.angelfire.com/linux/myp/MC/)